# Close a bootstrap warning when clicking anywhere on page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

[Bootstrap Warnings Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6mHY.png) I have two different types of bootstraps alerts (warning and danger). Danger alerts are always suppose to be on the page no matter what. Warning alerts happen when user clicks on the dropdown list carriers it displays a bootstrap warning notification. User has to click on 'x' for it to close. I need it to work when user click anywhere on the page or by clicking on the 'x'.

**HomeController.cs**

```
case "Carrier":
    var carrierid = (from foo in db.Carriers
                     where foo.ID == warningid
                     select foo.WarningID).Single();
    if (carrierid != null)
    {
        warning = (from warnings in db.Warnings
                   where warnings.IsActive == true && warnings.Id == carrierid
                   select warnings.WarningBody).SingleOrDefault();
        if (warning != null)
        {
            warning = ("<div class=\"alert alert-warning alert-dismissible\" id=\"myWarning\" role=\"alert\"><button type=\"button\" class=\"close\" data-dismiss=\"alert\" aria-label=\"Close\"><span aria-hidden=\"true\">&times;</span></button><strong>" +
            warning + "</strong></div>");
        }
        else
        {
            warning = "";
        }
    }
    else
    {
        warning = "";
    }
    return Json(warning, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
default:
    break;
```

**warningwriter.js**

```
           //// warning display script takes a value of warningid and warningcaller
            $(document).ready(function () {
                   var warningid = 0;
                   var warningcaller = "Universal";
                   loadWarnings(warningid, warningcaller);
             });
              $('#Phones').change(function () {
                   var warningid = $(this).val();
                   var warningcaller = "Phone";
                   loadWarnings(warningid, warningcaller);})
             $('#Carriers').change(function () {
                   var warningid = $(this).val();
                   var warningcaller = "Carrier";
                   loadWarnings(warningid, warningcaller);})
          function loadWarnings(warningid, warningcaller) {
$.getJSON("../Home/LoadWarnings", { warningID: warningid, warningCaller: warningcaller },
            function (warning) {
            var select = $('#warnings');
            select.append(warning);

    });    
};
```

Comment: This is something you'll need to do from JavaScript in the view, rather than in the controller.

Comment: Let me update the code.

Comment: The previous programmer did this and I'm not sure how to go about this, and I'm also new to MVC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have two different types of bootstraps alerts (danger and warning). You have to use ".alert-warning" because that is the one you want to get rid of when user did a mouse click anywhere on page. ".alert" is all of the bootstraps alerts, however, if you need to get rid of a certain type you can call the contextual classes(e.g., .alert-success, .alert-info, .alert-warning, and/or .alert-danger. https://v4-alpha.getbootstrap.com/components/alerts/

```
               $(document).click(function (event) {
                   $(".alert-warning").hide();
               });
```

Answer (score 2):

As Martin suggested, it's something you need to do in javascript.  I haven't tested this, but it would be something like:

```
$(document).click(function (event) {            
   $(".alert").hide();
});
```

This is basically, clicking anywhere on the page will hide any displayed alert.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () { 
     $("#myWarning").click(function () {  
         $(".alert").alert("close"); 
     }); 
 });
```

By doing this, u are making two things wrong:

1. You are binding the click event to an element, that possibly
   doesnt exist when the page is loaded.
2. You are binding the click
   event to a restricted element. This means that the alert wont be
   closed when u click **anywhere** on the page. In this case, only clicks on #myWarning will close the alert.

Finally, you should use what @Bryan already posted :)

Edit:

Assuming that u have a set of alerts that u always want to close on page load, add to this elements a way to identify them, for example a class "close-on-screenclick"

```
$(document).click(function () { 
     $(".close-on-screenclick.alert").alert("close");  
 });
```

.This should close those elements whenever a click is made on the screen

Comment: @Bryan code works, but it deletes my other universal modifications when I click on something.

Comment: I have some danger bootstrap alerts that are always suppose to be there. The warning bootstrap are the ones that I need to get rid of.

Comment: you could add an extra class to the alerts that u always want to close whenever the user clicks anywhere in the screen

Comment: How would I go about this @Jota.Toledo? I uploaded an image.

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: I put the .close-on-screenclick.alert in my warningwriter.js. Would I have to add anything in the HomeController.cs file? I implemented your code and I have to click on the 'x' to dismiss the warning bootstrap.